In pacakage `GGally` `ggparcoord`, I want add labels to the plot, but `geom_text` failed
In pacakage GGally ggparcoord, I want add labels to the plot, but geom_text failed, how to fix it ? Thanks!
library(GGally)
library(tidyverse)

  data <- iris

Create basic plot plot_basic
 plot_basic <- data %>%
  arrange(desc(Species)) %>%
    group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>%
  ggparcoord(
    columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 5, order = "anyClass",
    showPoints = TRUE, 
    title = "Original",
    alphaLines = 1
    
  ) + 
   scale_color_manual(values=c( "#69b3a2", "red", "darkblue") ) +
  
  theme(
    
    plot.title = element_text(size=10)
  ) +
  xlab("")

Create data frame label_data for adding labels
label_data <- cbind(ggplot_build(plot_basic)$data[[1]],
                    data %>%
                      arrange(desc(Species)) %>%
                      group_by(Species) %>%  slice(1:3) %>% pivot_longer(-Species))

Wish below geom_text add labels to plot_basic , but failed . How to fix it ?
plot_basic + 
  geom_text(data = label_data,aes(x = x,y =y ,label=value))


As the error message you should get is telling you, there is no column .ID in the data used for the labels. To fix that, add inherit.aes=FALSE. However, after a closer look I think simply binding to the layer data from ggplot_build will not work as the order of the datasets differ.
Instead I would suggest to bind only the values you want as label to the plot data:
plot_basic$data <- plot_basic$data |>
  bind_cols(label_data |> ungroup() |> select(label = value))

plot_basic +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = label)
  )



Thanks for your help , this is brilliant !  I need some time to understing all of them ！
